# Red5 Flex Application: Shared Object sends “change” or “delete” event only when server is started and client connects for the first time

Tags: apache-flex, red5, shared-objects

I have a shared object created in WebScope. when I start the server and clients connect for the first time, it sends `change` and `delete` events just fine. but after that it only sends `clear` event. any ideas?

Comment: I was creating my shared object in `appStart` and in `connect`, I was only accessing it and setting some attributes. So probably when the last client disconnected, the SO was destroyed and wasn’t available on subsequent connects? it should have thrown a NullPointerException, no? Anyway, I added a check in `connect` method to create the shared object if it’s not already created. solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use **SyncEvent.changeList** property, but what for?
I suggest you to iterate over data via **SharedObject.data** or **SyncEvent.data** properties.

```
 var busySO:SharedObject = ...;
 for each (var obj:Object in busySO.data) {
        ...
 }
```